# Exportar y leer una variable nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Estoy trayendo los datos de una API mediante unirest. Pero necesito luego poder usar el JSON que me llega desde afuera del unirest. He hecho muchas opciones y nada funciona.

```
import unirest from 'unirest';
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

var orderId;

var req = unirest('GET', `https://${process.env.api_key}:${process.env.api_password}@${process.env.store_name}.myshopify.com/admin/api/${process.env.api_version}/orders.json?name=8519`)
  .headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cookie': `${process.env.cookie}`
  })
  .end(function (res) { 
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error); 
    orderId = res.raw_body;
    return orderId;
  });
  
  console.log(orderId);
```

Comment: La respuesta de tu api la debes consumir dentro del callback que recibe `end()`.  Tu `console.log` se va a ejecutar antes de que se resuelva la petición, es obvio que no te funcionará. En donde dice `return orderId;` coloca ahí el `console.log(orderId);`. Repasa bien los conceptos de promesas y asincronía antes de consumir una api para que lo hagas bien.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Coloque el console.log fuera del end() como ejemplo de donde lo necesito. Quiero usar el contenido del orderId fuera del end().

Comment: Desafortunadamente no puedes. Crea una función que haga lo que sea que requieras hacer con esos datos y llámala dentro del end() pasandole los datos. Tu código no puede esperar por unos datos que pueden llegar o pueden no llegar (son una promesa). Eso si, si llegan, ellos js te asegura  ejecutar lo que sea que le solicites dentro del end()